# What driver is required for my Realtek wifi adapter 802.11n?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless

`lsusb` gives the following output for my newly purchased Realtek wifi adapter 802.11n

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

As a new Ubuntu/Linux user I want to know what driver is suitable for this USB device and how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

from link: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/blob/realtek-4.4.x/README.md 
you need to download the driver from ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DWA-131/REV_E/Drivers/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1.zip